# Why is 'for(var item in list)' with arrays considered bad practice in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

Given a simple zero based, numerically indexed array:

```
var list = ['Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz'];
```

Many times, I have noticed that when someone suggests looping through variables in an array like this:

```
for(var item in list) { ... }
```

...there's almost certainly someone suggesting that that's bad practice and suggests an alternative approach:

```
var count = list.length;

for(var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    var item = list[i];
    ...
}
```

What's the reasoning for not using the simpler version above and to use the second example instead?

Comment: You're not looping over the items with that loop, you're looping over the keys / property names / indizes.

Comment: Also C coders in victorian tophats not understanding iiterators.
However keep in mind its spitting out keys, not values. The for( ; ; ) format is faster, but 99% of the time, it really does not matter. Coder time is more expensive than computation time unless your working on megaprojects or stuff with a genuine need of optimization.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

First, the order of the loop is undefined for a `for...in` loop, so there's no guarantee the properties will be iterated in the order you want.

Second, `for...in` iterates over all enumerable properties of an object, including those inherited from its prototype. In the case of arrays, this could affect you if your code or any library included in your page has augmented the prototype of `Array`, which can be a genuinely useful thing to do:

```
Array.prototype.remove = function(val) {
    // Irrelevant implementation details
};

var a = ["a", "b", "c"];

for (var i in a) {
    console.log(i);
}

// Logs 0, 1, 2, "remove" (though not necessarily in that order)
```

Comment: thats fine as long as you use `hasOwnProperty` though - `for (var i in a) { if (a.hasOwnProperty(i)) console.log(i); }` -> 1 2 3

Comment: One suggestion, change `over all properties` to `over **enumerable** properties`. In newer javascript implementations, properties can be defined with the `enumerable` attribute set to `false`. These properties and properties of built-in javascript objects wouldn't show up in a `for...in`.

Comment: @Dimitar: Indeed, although once you've added that in, the loop has stopped looking simpler than a standard C-style for loop.

Comment: anyway - the only legitimate reason for looping an array like that is to obtain the array keys (which works due to nature of arrays in javscript) - any other reason, you better do a normal loop.

Answer (score 20):

Speed?

`for(..;..;..)` loop proved to be 36 times faster than `for .. in` [when I tested it here.](http://blogs.oracle.com/greimer/resource/loop-test.html)

[Link courtesy this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/157260/whats-the-best-way-to-loop-through-a-set-of-elements-in-javascript/157715#157715)

Comment: I misread that as infinite loop is 36x faster than a normal loop. Thanks for the link +1.

Comment: @Thomas Reasonable misunderstanding - when read out of context. Fixed :)

Answer (score 3):

**`for ... in ...` doesn't return items of list, but instead enumerates array properties.**

For that reason alone, it *cannot* act as a replacement of `for (i=0; i<arr.length; i++)` loop.

**The appropriate alternative is `for ... of ...` construct.** It enumerates values of an iterable object, such as an array. You can read more about it on MDN Web Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of

It's supported by the relevant modern browsers (Internet Explorer doesn't count, with it being replaced by Microsoft Edge). If you can afford not supporting older browsers, it's probably the way to go. You can check the convenient browser support table at the end of aforelinked MDN page to see which browser versions actually allow `for ... of ...` usage.

Comment: I'd would be so happy to know your assertion about IE could be true and trusted :)

Answer (score 1):

If you use for/in like that, `item` enumerates through string values "0", "1", ..., so not the actual objects in the list. So the the 'item' in the first snippet is more like the `i` in the second snippet,not the `item`. Furthermore string values are enumerated where you'd expect numbers. And you get in trouble when you properties to the list, like `array.ID = "a123"`, as they will get enumerated also.

But with these downsides, I still think the syntax is very useful, if your team is aware of what it does.

Answer (score 0):

Add `list.foo = bar;` and try to use simple `for`.
If you don't use some libraries(like prototypeJs) and don't add any new properties to array object - you can use simple for-statement.