# How to iterate json object string?

Tags: javascript, json, jqgrid

My JsonResult as follows

```
[{"name":"Group 1"},{"name":"Group 2"},{"name":"Group 3"}]
```

I'm little bit confused while writing for loop, so How to iterate over this or get the values of name inside buildSelect function in editoptions in jqGrid? My colModel code in jqGrid as follows

```
 { name: 'GroupName', index: 'GroupName', width: 60, align: 'center', search: false, editable: true, edittype: 'select',
   editoptions: {
                 dataUrl: "/Category/GetCategoryGroup",
                 buildSelect: function (response) {
                                  if (response && response.length) {
                                        // for loop iteration to get name values           
                                  }                                                 
                            }                                          
                 } 
 },
```

Comment: You don't know how to iterate over an array?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: @FelixKling: My question is not how to iterate over an array. Myself doesn't know how to use this inside function in buildSelect(jqGrid) and to return it as dropdownlist?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4102155/218196, the "UPDATED" section.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (response && response.length) {
    var contents='<select>';
    for(var i=0; i< response.length; i++){
        var t = response[i];
        var g_name = t.name;
        contents+="<option>"+g_name+"</option>";
    }
   contents+="</select>";
   document.getElementById("contentDropdown").innerHTML = contents; 
}
```

where you want to show dropdown create a div like this:

```
<div id="contentDropdown"></div>
```

hope this will help you.

Comment: You shouldn't use `for...in` to iterate over arrays. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265167/why-is-forvar-item-in-list-with-arrays-considered-bad-practice-in-javascript

Comment: @komal: sorry this not works inside buildSelect in jqGrid. I have to show these three groups in dropdownlist in jqGrid(form editing)

Answer (score 0):

```
var groups = [{"name":"Group 1"},{"name":"Group 2"},{"name":"Group 3"}];
for(var i = 0; i< groups.length; i++) {
 var name = groups[i].name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

same like an array

```
var myOb = [{"name":"Group 1"},{"name":"Group 2"},{"name":"Group 3"}] ; 

for (var i=0; i < myOb.length; i++) { 
 console.log(myOb[i]);
 console.log(myOb[i].name);
 console.log(myOb[i]['name']);
}
```

You can do further loop into edit options

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to iterate the array

```
var groups = [{"name":"Group 1"},{"name":"Group 2"},{"name":"Group 3"}]; 

$.each( groups, function() {
    alert(this.name);
});
```