# Jquery multidimensional Json parse

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Hey all below is my sample json data, I am good in php but new to jquery ,

```
   "data":{
        "cipher":"true",
        "size":[
            "2.2 Mb",
            "6.11 Mb",
            "9.25 Mb",
            "18.49 Mb",
            "23.79 Mb",
        ],
        "prop":[
            "small",
            "small",
            "small",
            "medium",
            "medium",
        ]
    }
```

I want something like below php code in jquery.

```
$i = 0
foreach($arr[data] as $test){
    echo $arr[data][size][$i];
    echo $arr[data][prop][$i];
    $i++;
}
```

I tried something like below

```
if(typeof response =='object'){
    console.log("valid json");
    $.each(response.data, function(i, object) {
        $.each(object, function(property, value) {

        });
    }); 
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/parse-json-in-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please don't use jQuery for that. jQuery is a tool for HTML DOM operations. You can just use regular JavaScript.

You can do either a `for` loop on your data, or use `.forEach` on an Array:

```
arr.data.size.forEach(function (value, index) {
  console.log('arr.data.size[' + index+ ']=', value)
  console.log('arr.data.prop[' + index+ ']=', arr.data.prop[index])
})
```

This will output:

```
arr.data.size[0]= 2.2 Mb
arr.data.prop[0]= small
arr.data.size[1]= 6.11 Mb
arr.data.prop[1]= small
arr.data.size[2]= 9.25 Mb
arr.data.prop[2]= small
arr.data.size[3]= 18.49 Mb
arr.data.prop[3]= medium
arr.data.size[4]= 23.79 Mb
arr.data.prop[4]= medium
```

Comment: thanks. There are some very nifty functions available for arrays: `forEach`, `map`, `filter`, `slice`, etc... you can Google for it. For looping over the keys of an object you can use `Object.keys(array.data).forEach(...)`

Comment: @JosdeJong I'm interested in your opinion. Do you think that `jQuery` in particular is not suitable for parsing `JSON` or you would prefer pure `JavaScript` instead any `lib`.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of jQuery, you should use a library like Underscore (http://underscorejs.org/) or Lodash (https://lodash.com/), which have a `zip` method that does just what you want.

(The purpose of jQuery is essentially to manipulate the DOM, the purpose of Underscore/Lodash is essentially to manipulate data.)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
            <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/2.4.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
            <script>
            var data = JSON.parse('{"cipher":"true","size":["2.2 Mb","6.11 Mb","9.25 Mb","18.49 Mb","23.79 Mb"],"prop":["small","small","small","medium","medium"]}');
            var z = _.zip(data.size, data.prop); // It all happens here
            console.log(z);
            $("body").append(JSON.stringify(z));
            </script>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title></title>
        </head>
        <body>
        </body>
    </html>
```

The console outputs an array of arrays:

```
[["2.2 Mb", "small"], ["6.11 Mb", "small"], ["9.25 Mb", "small"], ["18.49 Mb", "medium"], ["23.79 Mb", "medium"]]
```

See demo here: http://jsbin.com/rufeci/1/

Comment: You may want to explain _why_ he shouldn't use jQuery but another lib

Comment: @NicolasLeThierryd'Ennequin I think that was a suggestion of how to improve your answer, not a request for comments.

Answer (score 2):

Jquery is not required for this. Simple iteration should work--

```
for(var i in data.size){
    console.log(data.size[i]);
}

for(var i in data.prop){
    console.log(data.prop[i]);
}
```

Demo-- http://jsfiddle.net/RahulB007/j6826qk1/

Check result in console.

Comment: i wanted in single loop..accepting jos de jong answer...+1 anywa

Comment: `for (.. in ..)` can have some issues. I prefer to avoid it.

Comment: @TimSeguine : It do not have issues until used in wrong places. Although, simple for-loops(for(i=0;i<3;i++)) work everywhere. Anyways what kind of issues are we talking about?

Comment: @RahulB if someone modifies `Array.prototype`(which is legitimate although perhaps ill-advised) you can end up iterating over things that aren't actually in the array. It is probably unlikey to happen most of the time, but I prefer not to have to consider it.

Comment: @TimSeguine : So this will affect the array itself. So if you iterate by any other looping method also, they will fail, not just above approach.

Comment: @RahulB not if you loop by indices. Because it won't affect length.

Comment: @TimSeguine : Some what correct. I found a S.O question regarding this-- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265167/why-is-forvar-item-in-list-with-arrays-considered-bad-practice-in-javascript

Comment: @RahulB I know that link. I probably should have linked it myself. The answer also covers something I forgot to mention, that the iteration ordering is not defined. The inheritance problem is enough for me though.