# Javascript. Hey where will the return put the friend[i]?

Tags: javascript

where will the return put the friend[i]?

where will the return put the friend[i]?

where will the return put the friend[i]?

```
var friends = {
    steve: {
        firstName: "Steve",
        lastName: "Jobs",
        number: "(831)524-2213",
        address: ["531 Recht St.","Hollister","CA","95037"] 
    },
    bill: {
        firstName: "Bill",
        lastName: "Gates",
        number: "(831)524-0349",
        address: ["310 E Dunne Ave", "Morgan Hill", "CA","95037"]
    }
};
var search = function(name){
    for (var i=0;i<friends;i++){
        if (friends[i].firstName === name) {
            console.log(friends[i]);
            return friends[i];
        } 
    }
};
```

Comment: at line 19, where will the return put the friend[i]?

Comment: You have an object called friends not an array

Answer (score 1):

The problem is friends is an object not an array so your loop is wrong

If you want to keep `friends` as an object itself, then you need to iterate over the properties of that object

```
var search = function (name) {
    for (var key in friends) {
        if (friends.hasOwnProperty(key) && friends[key].firstName === name) {
            console.log(friends[key]);
            return friends[key];
        }
    }
};
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/jzvtjury/)

---

Or use an array instead

```
var friends = [{
    firstName: "Steve",
    lastName: "Jobs",
    number: "(831)524-2213",
    address: ["531 Recht St.", "Hollister", "CA", "95037"]
}, {
    firstName: "Bill",
    lastName: "Gates",
    number: "(831)524-0349",
    address: ["310 E Dunne Ave", "Morgan Hill", "CA", "95037"]
}];
var search = function (name) {
    for (var i = 0; i < friends.length; i++) {
        if (friends[i].firstName === name) {
            console.log(friends[i]);
            return friends[i];
        }
    }
};
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/jzvtjury/4/)

Comment: they says that for .. in loop is a bad practice... they say better use for(..;..;..) than for .. in . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265167/why-is-forvar-item-in-list-with-arrays-considered-bad-practice-in-javascript is that a true?

Comment: @jubilukbabawakis look at the title `Why is 'for(var item in list)' with arrays considered bad practice in JavaScript?` - it is related to handling arrays, in your case it is not an array...

Comment: ok ... I know now ... but where will the return put the return friends[key] ?

Comment: @jubilukbabawakis where you have it is fine... look at the attached fiddle to see it working