# Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined for JavaScript Array object

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here are my code:

```
var nestedArr = [[1, 2, 3], [5, 2, 1, 4]];
var result;

  for (var a = 0; a < nestedArr.length; a++) { // iterate nestedArr
    for (var b = 0; b < nestedArr[a].length; b++) {
      if (nestedArr[a+1].includes(nestedArr[a][b])) {
        result.push(nestedArr[a][b]);
    }
  }
}
```

Output: `Error: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined`. But at least I can make sure several things: 
1. `includes()` method exists for array in JavaScript
2. Run a single statement `nestedArr[a+1];` in console give me the array `[5, 2, 1, 4]`

So, I really don't understand the `Error`? Please help me figure out this. Thanks.

Comment: the last index plus one does not exist.

Comment: What does this code intend to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

The program will search for an index that doesn't exist.

```
var nestedArr = [[1, 2, 3], [5, 2, 1, 4]];
  ...
    ...
      if (nestedArr[a+1].includes(nestedArr[a][b])) {
      // As nestedArr.length will return 2, the program will eventually  search for nestedArr[2+1 (=3)] which doesn't exist.
    }
  }
}
```

**Bonus:** Why not use `for var i in nestedArr` instead of using `.length`

[Take a look at this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2265195/2246164)

Answer (score 1):

```
var nestedArr = [[1, 2, 3], [5, 2, 1, 4]];
var result = [];

  for (var a = 0; a < nestedArr.length; a++) { // iterate nestedArr
    for (var b = 0; b < nestedArr[a].length; b++) {
      if (nestedArr[a].includes(nestedArr[a][b])) {
        result.push(nestedArr[a][b]);
    }
  }
}
console.log(result)
```

removing the plus one did the job, basically you tried to access an array were no arrays were present

Answer (score 0):

As @Nina Scholz commented

> the last index plus one does not exist

You don't need to check by includes ! Just do loop and assign using `filter` and `map` as example !!!

```js
var nestedArr = [[1, 2, 3], [5, 2, 1, 4]];
    var result = [];
    nestedArr.filter( (val) => {
      val.map( (v) => { result.push(v); } )
    })
    console.log(result);
```