# converting code from jquery to pure javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to loop though some links and add a number to the href, so it would be something like `x.php&ref=333`.

```
<div id="maindiv">
<span><a href="x.php&ref="></a></span>
<span><a href="x.php&ref="></a></span>
<span><a href="x.php&ref="></a></span>
</div>
```

How do I write this in pure javascript? Here is the jQuery code:

```
$('#maindiv a').each(function(){
var hr = $(this).attr('href');
$(this).attr('href' , hr+333 );
})
```

For some reason I can't use that and need to write the code in pure javascript .
Specifically, I don't know how to get each `a` element.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the best way to loop through a set of elements in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/157260/whats-the-best-way-to-loop-through-a-set-of-elements-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pure JS versions:

**Option One**

```
// Get div element. jQuery equivalent: $('#maindiv')
var mainDiv = document.getElementById("maindiv");

// Get all anchors in element. jQuery equivalent: $('#maindiv a') (or many others)
var myAnchors = mainDiv.getElementsByTagName("a");

// Loop through each anchor element and update href
for (var i = 0; i < myAnchors.length; i++) {
    myAnchors[i].href = myAnchors[i].href + "YourString";
}​
```

**Option Two (tiny bit less readable)**

```
// Get div element and corresponding anchors. jQuery equivalent: $('#maindiv a')
var myAnchors = document.getElementById("maindiv").getElementsByTagName("a");

// Loop through each anchor element and update href
for (var i = 0; i < myAnchors.length; i++) {
    myAnchors[i].href = myAnchors[i].href + "YourString";
}​
```

**Additional Information**

Check out [document.getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementById) and [element.getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName) ON MDN.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
var anchors = document.getElementById("maindiv").getElementsByTagName("a");
for(var i = 0; i < anchors.length;i++){
    anchors[i].href = anchors[i].href + "333";
}
```

[document.getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementById) returns the element with matching id within the document.

[document.getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName) returns the element with matching tag within the document. But if you call `getElementsByTagName` on an already selected element like above it will look within that element.

Comment: it appears that you've rolled back my edit. `getElementsByTagName{"a");` should be `getElementsByTagName("a");`

Comment: No worries - I knew it was with a 27.7k user :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var els = document.querySelectorAll('#maindiv a');
for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++ ) {
    var hr = els[i].href;
    els[i].href = hr + 333;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be the cleanest way to do it.

```
var links = document.getElementById('maindiv').getElementsByTagName('a');
for (i in links) {
  links[i].href = links[i].href + '333';
}
```